# «Can't create domain» error on installing Vesta admin panel

Tags: installation, centos, centos6, administration, vesta

I trying to install VestaCP on CentOS 6. And i always get this error:

```
Error: no avaiable IP address
Error: can't create domain
```

I install Vesta on clean OS and installation have no special configuration that can cause this errors.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Open vst-install-rhel.sh (for example, with «nano») and delete this block:

```
# Adding default domain
$VESTA/bin/v-add-domain admin $servername
check_result $? “can’t create $servername domain”
```

Than run vst-install-rhel.sh:

```
bash vst-install-rhel.sh
```

See also:
[Vesta Forum](https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=10248), [Russian Admin Blog](http://odminblog.ru/vesta-install-error/)